# Changing slider value of custom transport control gives an exception {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

With the sample app:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be#content

Custom transport control is not working. Moving slider thumb gives an exception:

> BasicMediaPlayback.exe!SDKTemplate.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__9(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50 C#

with no other call stack entries.

I also tried putting

```
await Task.Delay(500);
```

and stopping timer before actually updating the timeslider value or mediaelemnet position
 but still getting same exception. The problem is, control is not even going to the event handler. I get same exception even if I remove the evenhandlers attached in code behind.

do I need to set anything before running this scenario? Am I missing something?
 please help.

Comment: I also tried recording mp3 format from my laptop and then playing that recording, I face the same slider issue.
 you can use:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

to capture the audio.
 But if I download some mp3 from internet, the scenario works just fine.

 I will try to explore more and then post my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh got it finally :)
The statement:

```
stepFrequency = Math.Round(timevalue.TotalSeconds / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

sets stepFrequency to zero if the Audio is too short.

Just added:

```
stepFrequency = Math.Round(timevalue.TotalSeconds / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            if (stepFrequency == 0)
            {
                stepFrequency = 1;
            }
```

to make it work.
Thank you Guys :)

Comment: Comparing a double against 0 is a really bad idea. You should use a epsilon.

Comment: Agree with you @ClausJørgensen,

I am just trying to explain the reason why it was happening
And how to overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check the Minimum and Maximum values set on the slider, along with the value it is set on.

Comment: yes. I did that check.
the line:
`Scenario4MediaElement.SetSource(stream, this.m_recordStorageFile.FileType);`

Automatically sets the maximum and minimum values.
To be on safe side, I also tried setting these values in xaml.
But didn't help